# In a filename, is the dot . a part of the file extension?

Tags: file, definition

A file has a filename and an extension and these are usually written with a dot (a full stop) between them as a delimiter. This description tells us that the dot is not a part of the extension but when stating extension we usually include the dot.

For example a PNG file with filename "image" is usually written as image.png. But we usually say the .png extension like the dot is a part of the extension. I'm just curious, is the dot a delimeter between them or a part of the extension, i.e. is the extension "png" or is it ".png"?

Comment: Matter of opinion … which will likely vary depending on context.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension) on File extensions:

> The exact definition, giving the criteria for deciding what part of the file name is its extension, belongs to the rules of the specific filesystem used; usually the extension is the **substring which *follows* the last occurrence, if any, of the dot character**.

"png" is technically the file extension, though you always look for the file extension after the *final* full-stop.

Comment: An interesting point to bring up is with *.tar.gz files, which are actually two files, a tar archive that is then compressed into a gzip file. Just a much seen example of double extensions.

Comment: At the same time, in Windows, [extension](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/f/fileext.htm) includes the dot char. For example, in cmd script, for 'filename.ext' [%~x1](https://www.computerhope.com/call.htm) expands to extension _with_ the dot—'.ext'. But, if filename ends with the dot char ('filename.'), %~x1 expands to empty string, not to single dot char.

Answer (score 0):

In the .NET APIs, the dot is considered part of the extension.

- [System.IO.Path.GetExtension(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Path_GetExtension_System_String_)

> This method obtains the extension of path by searching path for a period (.), starting with the last character in path and continuing toward the first character. If a period is found before a `DirectorySeparatorChar` or `AltDirectorySeparatorChar` character, **the returned string contains the period and the characters after it**; otherwise, `String.Empty` is returned.

```cs
// GetExtension('C:\mydir.old\myfile.ext') returns '.ext'
// GetExtension('C:\mydir.old\') returns ''
```

This was important information for me since I'm modeling a class that relies on a configurable file extension for a certain activity, so I included the `.` character as part of the text for the property value:

```cs
public string CacheFileExtension { get; } = ".cache"
```

Comment: I've always regarded this behavior as incorrect - the 'dot' is irrelevant.

Comment: @Robear it may very well be (I don't have a strong opinion on it personally), but that's beside the point. You have to program as per the rules defined by the framework you are targeting, so having the dot as part of the extension is the way to go in .Net IMHO.

Answer (score -3):

`png` is the extension, although without the `.` it would just a be a default file format, which can’t be opened